# SQL Server 2008 R2 - EXISTS vs TOP 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the past we had a stored function, which looked essentially like this:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... ) RETURN 1
```

Where the SELECT would take quite a long time to execute, however, with EXISTS wrapped around we are pretty fast finished.

However we now need a "certificate" in the application, "give me one example why you returned 1". We changed the query to:

```
DECLARE @cert BIGINT
SELECT TOP 1 @cert = id FROM ...
RETURN @cert
```

However, this takes a much longer time now. We do not have an `ORDER BY` clause in our query.

Is SQL Server still retrieving ALL rows and just selecting the first afterwards? 
Did we oversee something? Shouldn't we have the same speed?
Why does the second query take so much more time than the first one? (magnitudes of time)

Comment: have you tried to use data execution plan?

Comment: what is the question here ...

Comment: we are not really able to execute this function only (yes, not optimal...), and if we look at the query plan of the base procedure which is somewhere down the stack trace calling our function we only get the base procedure's plan...

Comment: @Mingebag: Look at the question marks? :-) Why do those two select statements do not have the same performance?

Comment: As side question, without ordering, how do you get the correct id?

Comment: It may depend on expression behind these three dots (...). For EXISTS it is usually enough (for SQL server) to check some related table or index records count, no actual data reads are required. To get any field value, SQL needs to read actual data, which does take more time. Can you look for @cert (ID) value in some other part of your query? Is ID field indexed?

Comment: TOP 1 does not insulate you from the engine going out and doing all the work.  I once thought I could use that as a safety catch on a query which went looking for duplicates.  One bad input file later (with 25,000 duplicates which caused a cartesian join with hundreds of millions of matches) I learned otherwise.  TOP 1 does not protect you.

Answer (score 3):

Your if exists checks the existence of a matching condition and stops after it finds one, but never has to return the result. I believe that as soon as you are selecting from the set, it has to return something and depending on the set it could take awhile for the top evaluation?

If it is taking a long time, I would investigate the execution plan and see if any indexes are available to you to add.

Comment: I would give the same answer totally agree !!